# Stop qt writing to /dev/tty0

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, embedded

I'm new to QT, so maybe question is too obvious for experts. I have an QT GUI app on embedded Linux system, which is constantly trying to write down input from keyboard to /dev/tty0. Of course I can restrict permissions to this device, but I would like to find more elegant solution. Can I somehow stop QT doing that? 
QT version: 4.8.1

stty -F /dev/tty0 -echo 
Solves the problem until next restart. Is there a way to disable echo on QT level?

[upd]
I found this guy with similar problem: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4778
But compiling QT with -qt-kbd-tty does not solve the problem.

Even if I setup "QWS_KEYBOARD" environment to "TTY:/dev/null" - keyboard stops working but echo is still active.

[UPD2] Solution: Can be done by setting environment
QWS_DISPLAY to "LinuxFb:tty=/dev/null"

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to actually solve?

Comment: /dev/tty0 is forwarded to the screen buffer as console output. I do get char '1' on screen as a result of key1 press. Which is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by setting environment QWS_DISPLAY to "LinuxFb:tty=/dev/null"